# OpenCV Freetype2 getTextSize always return 1 height

Tags: c++, linux, opencv, raspberry-pi

I'm trying to generate images on NanoPi NEO using OpenCV.
Currently using Armbian bionic and OpenCV 4.3.0 (built from sources with freetype2 module).
The problem is that Freetype2::getTextSize() method always returns 1 as text height. But width seems to be calculated fine. And on desktop PC same code works as expected.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/freetype.hpp>

int main() {
    cv::Ptr<cv::freetype::FreeType2> ft2;
    int baseline = 0;

    ft2 = cv::freetype::createFreeType2();
    ft2->setSplitNumber( 8 );
    ft2->loadFontData("../gobold.ttf", 0);

    cv::Size textSize = ft2->getTextSize("asdfg", 20, -1, &baseline);
    std::cout << "Height = " << textSize.height << " Width = " << textSize.width << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

This code returns "Height = 1 Width = 49" on Raspberry and "Height = 18 Width = 49" on desktop with same .ttf file.

Comment: What OS is running on your Desktop? Also, there is an opened issue related to this: https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib/issues/2444 But it seems that it will not be fixed soon

Comment: This commit fixes the bug. Hope it will be integrated soon> https://github.com/Kumataro/opencv_contrib/commit/39ffff662d0a19293f20f2f7b18cfc6b701aad9c